# Member-Function-Scoped Variable

Tags: c++, static, scope

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int foo() {
        // Can I get this to be an instance-specific static variable, please?
        static int i = 0;
        return i++;
    }
};

int main() {
    X a, b;
    std::cout << a.foo() << ' ';
    std::cout << b.foo() << ' ';
    std::cout << b.foo() << '\n';
    // output is: 0 1 2
    // desired output: 0 0 1
}
```

Is it possible to get a copy of this static variable `i` for each instance of `X` without the need to move the declaration and initialization to some far, far away headers and constructors?

The reason I want this, is because the value of this variable is only relevant within this specific function (but also specific to the instance whose member function it is), e.g., last call parameters, time of last call etc.

The class that stands behind this idea is already somewhat large and spreading the declaration and the initialization of such tiny variables that are used within one single function is getting ugly.

**Update:** Note that I don't want to leak memory. When an instance is destroyed, the variables associated with it should be removed as well.

**Update²:** Apparantly (and unfortunately) there is indeed no proper language feature with this exact semantics. 
While there are some workarounds, each of them introduces limitations and pitfalls when it comes to

- placement of "function" declaration and definition
- accessing other "real" member variables
- overloading the "function" in a derived class
- ...

With these implications in mind it just appears most efficient to stick with the first thing that comes to mind:

```
struct A {
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int foo() { return i++ + j++; }
};
```

rather than going for something like this:

```
struct B {
    int j = 0;
    std::function<int()> foo = 
        [this, i = 0]() mutable { return i++ + this->j++; };
};
```

or this:

```
struct C {
    int j;
    struct Foo {
        int i; 
        C *c;
        Foo(C *c) : i(), c(c) {}
        int operator() () { return i++ + c->j++; }
    } foo;
    C() : j(), foo(this) {}
};
```

or this:

```
struct D {
   int j = 0;
   std::map<std::string, int> i;
   int foo() { return i[__PRETTY_FUNCTION__]++ + j++; }
};
```

or similar.

Many thanks for your comments and answers!

Comment: so you want a static variable that's instance specific? Doesn't that violate the purpose of `static` in the case where it's used inside class/structs?

Comment: @TonyTheLion But this `static` is not used inside a class, it's used inside a function.

Comment: Nope you can't do that, you have to make it a class member. Full stop.

Comment: To be petty, you don't want static variable. you want function-scoped member variable. Nothing static about it.

Comment: @Elazar please don't suggest such things.  Some compiler might actually implement it :((

Comment: I hear you stating two goals (1) functionality you need (2) software engineering goal of something you think is pretty.  Unfortunately C++ only gives you one way to get (1) and it does not seem to meet your idea of (2).

Comment: With my understanding of [evaluation order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), isn't it the case that the three function calls could be evaluated in any order, so your output could theoretically be "0 2 1"? This also means that your desired output could also be "0 0 1". Not sure how the evaluation order is affected by ostreams, mind.

Comment: @icabod: that is correct.

Comment: If the real problem is "too many member variables are making my class declaration unmanageable", perhaps the solution is to refactor how you're declaring member variables.  i.e. instead of 300 separate int member variables, create a single member variable that is an array of 300 ints (and, optionally, an enum to name them, so you don't have to use magic numbers when referring to them).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That seems like a backwards step. If you need three hundred numbers, have three hundred numbers, not an array of three hundred numbers and then three hundred names with which to refer to them; no need to re-invent variable naming. Of course the _real_ solution is to stop needing three hundred numbers.

Comment: If they are completely unrelated to each other, then I agree.  But it would be unusual to have 300 completely unrelated variables, I think -- usually you can group them into sets of things where each member of the set is representing a different instance of the same data; at which point each set can become an array (or whatnot)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Right, but my point is that that only makes your life _harder_, not _easier_. :) BTW please use "@notification" syntax; I stumbled upon your reply only by accident.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It only makes your life harder until the first time you need to iterate across all the values... then you're glad you did it ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: True!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Two alternative options are available to you:

1. Make the variable a member, which is the language feature with the semantics you want;
2. or invent a new language.

I do understand your concern, but it really only stems from your `class` apparently being *too large*. Separate its responsibilities.

Comment: @AlvinWong It's C++, what does JDK have to do with it?

Comment: @Malcolm I think I ought to say gcc, but...? (my brain hurts)

Answer (score 6):

My turn:

```
struct X {
    class _foo {
        int i;
    public:
        _foo() : i(0) { }
        int operator()(void) {
            return i++;
        }
    } foo;
};
```

Basically, function-static variable makes the function an object (identity, state, behavior). You just don't want it to be singleton. So here it is - a class.

Comment: Won't each instance get a different version of `foo`? Make it `static` and it will be a condensed version of my answer.

Comment: You have to look twice, but at least the initialization is a little closer at hand :)

Comment: @PeterWood I want each instance to get a different instance of foo.

Comment: With C++11, you can have `i` initialized in-class and turn the class into an anonymous struct, then you have something that is pretty simple.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this is what you want:

```
struct X {
    X() : i(0) {}  // initialize variable on construction

    int foo() {
        // Can I get this to be an instance-static variable, please?
        return i++;
    }

    int i; // instance variable
};
```

Edit: Alternative without member variable, for those who don't look for simple options:

```
typedef std::map<X*,int> XMap;
static XMap xMap;

struct X {
    X() { xMap.insert(this, 0); }
    ~X() { xMap.erase(this); }

    int foo() {
        return xMap[this]++;
    }
};
```

Edit: same as above, but without constructor/destructor:

```
struct X {
    int foo() {
        return xMap[this]++;  // same as below:
        // XMap::iterator it = xMap.find(this);
        // if (it == xMap.end())
        // {
        //     it = xMap.insert(XMap::value_type(this, 0)).first;
        // }
        // return *it++;
    }
};
```

Comment: This produces the desired output, but it's not exactly what I want. Indeed, this is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: @moooeeeep But it's the only way. Think about how the compiler would know these: Where to allocate space for the variable? Which one belongs to a particular instace? The only way is to make it a member of the instance.

Comment: Yes, probably I'm looking for syntactic sugar for this exact thing.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Note that the "static map" option also requires the class to overload its copy constructor and copy assignment operator to keep the map in sync - I can't see this being worth the trouble.

Comment: @moooeeeep There can't really be syntactic sugar for that. The definition of `X` can be in a header while the body of `foo()` is compiled into a library. How could clients of this library (who can even load it dynamically) know to allocate extra space for each instance of `X` in addition to what's listed in the header?

Comment: @Angew The constructor can be avoided (just check before use), but the cleanup - only if there is no risk running out of memory. Using data segment assumes, it might be not an issue. Many performance counting facilities are accumulating information till end of test, and only after that clean statistics up.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk The caveats of removing the ctors + dtor are: 1) copying the instance (such as pass/return by value) resets the counter; 2) instances which happen to have the same address (such as a local var. inside a function called twice in a row) will share the counter.

Comment: @Angew You are right. But I can't think of many options without using compiler's instrumentation facilities.

Comment: The last example could be turned into a simple `return xMap[this]++` though. No need to check for existence, `[]` already does that.

Comment: @ChristianRau and what will be the default value? ´int()´?

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Exactly, therefore `0` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). In the end even if it didn't (but it does), `insert` would have been sufficient already, since it also checks for existence.

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate the function state in a lambda, contained in a `std::function` member:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    std::function<int()> foo = [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; };
};
int main() {
    X a, b;
    std::cout << a.foo() << " " << b.foo() << " " << b.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Note that this uses lambda generalized capture, a C++14 feature but already supported by g++ (since 4.7.2 at least).  Otherwise, you can manually rewrite the lambda into a (more efficient) functor:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    struct { int i = 0; int operator()() { return i++; } } foo;
};
int main() {
    X a, b;
    std::cout << a.foo() << " " << b.foo() << " " << b.foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's encapsulated inside a callable member, which improves textual locality.

Answer (score 1):

Is `foo` the only method of `X`? It seems you just want a convenient way to create counters then:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<int()> create_counter()
{
    int i = 0;
    return [=]() mutable { return i++; };
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = create_counter();
    auto b = create_counter();

    std::cout << a() << '\n';
    std::cout << a() << '\n';
    std::cout << b() << '\n';
    std::cout << b() << '\n';
    std::cout << b() << '\n';
    std::cout << b() << '\n';
    std::cout << a() << '\n';
}
```

Hint: You'll get much better answers if you refrain from using names such as `X` and `foo` ;-)

Comment: That looks interesting - my example is of course heavily simplified. More specifically I want to keep track of the last call parameter and the time of the last call (to compute the duration between two calls then).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method `GetVariableI(X)` that would accept an instance of X and return an instance-specific value, or a static value when null is passed.

That approach should solve your problem, however it is silly. It does what you say you want, but almost for sure not what you need. What is the behaviour you're trying to achieve? If you could elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, we could offer an alternative (and sane) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [Literate Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/lp.html) by Knuth.  It did stuff like this.  Basically you want a macro language that lets you move around text.

Answer (score 0):

Extending, and slightly obfuscating, Valeri Atamaniouk's answer, this seems to do the trick without the need for any member variables.

```
struct X {
    int foo() {
        struct l_int {
            int i;
            l_int():i(0) {};
        };
        static std::map<X*,l_int> i_map;
        return (i_map[this]).i++;
    }
};
```

I don't condone it as I think it's horrible, and would probably fall over when you tried copying objects around, but there you go.  Also, yes, it does leak a little memory each time you destroy an object.

The reason for storing the value in a struct is that you can be sure it will be initialised to zero when you create a new entry in the `std::map`, which will happen for each new object on calling `foo()`.

This program gives me `0 1 0` as an output, but I refer to my comment above about the order of evaluation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will leak memory when I destroy my X when I'm done with it.

Comment: Hey, I never said it was perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.  Isn't very clean conceptually, but it does handle the technical issue of putting your function and your variable closer together, while staying fairly simple:

```
struct XFoo {
    XFoo() : i(0) { }

    int foo() { return i++; }

    private:
        int i;
};

struct X : XFoo {
  // lots of stuff here
};
```

or with C++11:

```
struct XFoo {
    int foo() { return i++; }

    private:
        int i = 0;
};
```